# How to Determine Indentation: Converting Java Source FIle to HTML File

Tags: java, string, parsing, whitespace

I'm trying to programatically convert a Java source file into an HTML file using `PrintWriter` to write to a seperate .html file

Example source file may look like this. 
**HelloWorld.java:**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
            // Disregard this ridiculous example
        }
    }
}
```

All My printing works fine except I have a problem with indentation.  Everyting is aligned left.

**HelloWorld.html** (as seen in browser):

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World!");

while (true) {
System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
// Disregard this ridiculous example
}
}
}
```

**Program Source Code Snippet: I want this program to determine for me, which line in the java source code should get indentation when it is being converted to HTML. I don't want to do it manually, because then I'd have to write a different program for every source file**

```
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newFile);

    output.print("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>"
            + "<style>"
            + ".keyword { font-weight: bold; color: blue}"
            + "</style></head><body>");

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if (keywordSet.contains(tokens[i])) {
                // Gives Java keyword bold blue font
                output.print("<span class=\"keyword\">");
                output.print(tokens[i] + " ");
                output.print("</span>");
            } else {
                output.print(tokens[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        output.print("<br/>");
    }

    output.print("</body><html>");
    output.close();
```

**Note: The reason I `split()` each line is because certain keywords that may be in that line, are doing to be highlighted in the html file, which I do with a `<span>`, as noted in my code**

In the program source code, I obviously don't have any indenting implementation, so I know why I don't have indentation in the html file.  I really don't know how to go about implementing this.

How do I determine which line gets indentation, and how much indentation?

**EDIT:**
**My Guess: Determine how much whitespace is in the line before splitting it, save the into a variable, then print those spaces in for form of &nbsp's before I print anything else in the line.  But how do I determine how much whitespace is at the beginning of the line?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what I was trying to accomplish

```
        ...

        int whiteSpace = 0;

        while (whiteSpace < line.length() && Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(j))) {
            whiteSpace++;
        }

        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

        // Print white space
        for (int i = 0; i < whiteSpace; i++) {
            output.print("&nbsp");
        }

        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use a CSS class with `white-space: pre` or `pre-line` or `pre-wrap`.
2. You can wrap each line in a `<p>` with a calculated `margin-left`. It could be a multiple of `10px`, for example.  This would let you also change brace styles.

Basically, you'll have to keep a variable, `indentLevel`.  Increment it for each `{` not in a string or a comment, and decrement it for each `}` not in a string or a comment.  Indent each line, say `10px` times the indent level.  Test; do you want continuation lines indented more?

Comment: My question is more of a Java Question than it is a formatting question.  I was trying to have the program determine which line in the source code should get how much indentation when it's converting it to the HTML file.

Comment: @Eric what will the `<pre>` tag do for me?

Comment: The <pre> tag tells the browser to respect white-space.  The CSS attribute does the same, and the `pre-line` and `pre-wrap` values do slightly more sophisticated things. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pre](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag.

> The  tag defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually
>   Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

You don't need to dermine which line needs to be indented because `pre` tag preserves ALL spaces, carriage returns and line feeds 'as-is' from the original HTML source code.

If you check the HTML that is rendered in StackOverflow in something marked as code you will see that it uses this tag.

Comment: I think this won't help, he is splitting each line of code to find the keywords using String.split(), so indentation spaces are lost.

Comment: I totally understand about the white space and how to implement it in HTML, but my question is, how do I determine, in my programattically, which line from from my source code should get indentation, when I convert it to my HTML file

Comment: And the reason I am splitting is because I'm adding a `<span class="keyword">` to certain keywords in the String.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to first prepare String with your source code adding needed HTML, and replacing spaces with `&nbsp;`. This can be done with String.replace() method - iterate over you keywordSet and replace all keywords with its wrapped versions. Then you will able to write full string into your stream.

Comment: The only thing wrong with this approach, is that I'm manually inserting the space.  I want to do it programatically.  That's why I need my program to determine where the spacing goes. In your case, I would have to manually space every source file. I'm trying to create a program where I can just pass it a source file and it will automatically convert it for me.

Comment: It's not trivial, you'll have to parse your code by tokens, then implement all the indentation logic for desired formatting rules to print it. You can begin with counting the curly braces :)

Comment: I really only need to count the white space in the front of each line that I'm getting from the source file. Then I can just print that white space to the html before printing anything else. But I don't know how to determine how much whitespace there is.  That's my real problem. The rest I can handle.